# Can I create Solspace Calendar from front end?

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

I see in docs that I can create event for calendar in front end (https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v3/templating-extras/events-front-end.html#example-code-from-demo-templates). Can I create a new calendar in the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a calendar from the front end is currently not possible.